# What is the rationale for `reject_if`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cocoon-gem

I've come across `reject_if` in cocoon's [README](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), and also in the documentation for [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). What is the rationale for using `reject_if` when the associated active record objects can determine whether they're valid or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested objects, you may not want to attempt to submit a record that is `:all_blank` or for any other reason you may want to check on. The point being, an empty or incomplete (in some way) object can, this way, simply not be built / added to the nested objects collection.

Validations serve a different purpose. If an empty object, say, fails validation then the whole form submit will fail. The `reject_if` approach allows submission to succeed in such a case by removing the object from consideration before validations fire.

Comment: But why not use active record validation for that?

Comment: Updated to explain why validations are different.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails guides has a description of the rationale for `:reject_if`, though it doesn't explicitly compare this option to just validating the sub-objects:

> [9.5 Preventing Empty Records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#preventing-empty-records)
>
> It is often useful to ignore sets of fields that the user has not
>   filled in. You can control this by passing a `:reject_if` proc to
>   `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. This proc will be called with each
>   hash of attributes submitted by the form. If the proc returns `false`
>   then Active Record will not build an associated object for that hash.
>   The example below only tries to build an address if the `kind`
>   attribute is set.
>
> ```
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :addresses
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
> end
> ```
>
> As a convenience you can instead pass the symbol `:all_blank` which
>   will create a proc that will reject records where all the attributes
>   are blank excluding any value for `_destroy`.